# Is there a way to vectorize this and have it output identical to the b_loop? This is in R

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization

```
require(dplyr)
...
a <- data.frame(col1 = 1:10)
b_vectorize <- a %>% 
  mutate(col1 = lag(col1, 1))
b_loop <- a
for(i in 2:10){
  b_loop$col1[i] <- b_loop$col1[i-1]
}
print(a)
print(b_vectorize)
print(b_loop)
```

P.S. I am new to R and would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Do you mean you want `b_vectorize` same as `b_loop `?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want `b_vectorize` same `as b_loop` output

```
b_vectorize <- a %>% 
    mutate(col1 = c(first(col1) , diff(col1)))
```

- output

```
   col1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    1
```